# Exchange 2010 and Office 2010 for PC and Mac OSX

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

We are looking for a way for a group of people to have access to a Mailbox (easy part, open shared mailbox in outlook for PC and for Mac - Add additional account on Mobile Phones etc).

We want the users to send on behalf of this Mailbox (again easy).

The tricky part comes when we want to have the sent emails go into the Sent Items of the shared mailbox.. (and dont say "why would you want that, thats not the design blah blah blah)

We also want the reply to come from the user who sent the email on the behalf.

Any help with these two issues would be greatly appreciated.